# Export to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm exporting the values in the grid to excel through C# code. When i open the exported excel, the string column is displayed as integer and the leading '0' in that field gets deleted. how to handle this.

Comment: What's the library that you're using for creating the excel file?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a programming issue; it's Excel's default way of displaying what it thinks are numbers.

It assumes that `00001` is a number and should be displayed as `1`. Change your cells to display "Text" instead of numbers in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in making Excel files but when entering text in Excel you can write '00123.
The ' makes the whole difference.

Answer (score 0):

Style the TDs with `mso-number-format:\@`

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get around this is to prefix your cell value with an apostrophe.

*Excel hides the apostrophe automatically* and forces the text mode for the cell to `Text`

Try it directly in Excel and you'll see what I mean eg type `'07799123477` into a cell with `General` text formatting (the default)